# Update Priority of other records based on New record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with a column called Priority (int) with values from 1 to n.

E.g. I have the following 6 records with Priority column:

```
Col1 | Priority
-----+----------
val1 | 1
val2 | 2
val3 | 3
val4 | 4
val5 | 5
val6 | 6
```

Now i inserted a new record val7 with priority 2. val2 will change priority 3 and after 2 all records priority should increment by 1. So output would be

```
Col1 | Priority
-----+---------
val1 | 1
val7 | 2
val2 | 3
val3 | 4
val4 | 5
val5 | 6
val6 | 7
```

How can I do this in T-SQL ?

Comment: Simply do an `UPDATE`!

Comment: if 100 records are there and new record is inserted with priority 1 then i have to update 100 records means 100 times update  query should run

Comment: Only one UPDATE is needed.

Comment: BTW, tables have _rows_, not records.

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET Priority = Priority + 1 where ...`